# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name jwtAutheticationFilter Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field userDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring security in my project. and I am getting this error which says

Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAutheticationFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService': Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigs': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtAutheticationFilter': Error creating bean with name 'jwtAutheticationFilter': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

below is the full stack of error log

```
2023-11-01T11:59:53.866+05:30  WARN 21524 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
2023-11-01T11:59:54.458+05:30  INFO 21524 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2023-11-01T11:59:54.519+05:30  INFO 21524 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-11-01T11:59:54.718+05:30 ERROR 21524 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAutheticationFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService': Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigs': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtAutheticationFilter': Error creating bean with name 'jwtAutheticationFilter': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2023-11-01T11:59:54.732+05:30  INFO 21524 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-11-01T11:59:54.734+05:30  WARN 21524 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-11-01T11:59:54.735+05:30  WARN 21524 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-11-01T11:59:54.737+05:30  WARN 21524 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2023-11-01T11:59:54.737+05:30  INFO 21524 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-11-01T11:59:54.740+05:30  INFO 21524 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-11-01T11:59:54.747+05:30  INFO 21524 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-11-01T11:59:54.754+05:30  INFO 21524 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-11-01T11:59:54.765+05:30 ERROR 21524 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  jwtAutheticationFilter (field private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.codewithdurgesh.blog.sequrity.JwtAutheticationFilter.userDetailsService)
↑     ↓
|  securityConfigs (field private com.codewithdurgesh.blog.sequrity.JwtAutheticationFilter com.codewithdurgesh.blog.configs.SecurityConfigs.jwtAutheticationFilter)
└─────┘
```

here are all the the classes which i have created.

**JwtAutheticationFilter class**

```
package com.codewithdurgesh.blog.sequrity;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class JwtAutheticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JWTTokenHelper jwtTokenHelper;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // this method will get calls whenever user tries to access API and sent request

//      1. GET token from request
//      we get token in the form of Bearer eybxsghdjtuwoqzmglhdnvi

        String requestToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        System.out.println("request token is " + requestToken);

        String userName = null;
        String token = null;

        if (requestToken != null && requestToken.startsWith("Bearer")) {
//          need to remove Bearer from the request token to get the actual token

            token = requestToken.substring(7);
            try {
                userName = jwtTokenHelper.getUsernameFromToken(token);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("unable to get the JWT token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println(" the JWT token is expired");
            } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("jwt invalid ");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("the JWT token is not correct");
        }

//       once we get the token, now validate
//      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() = null meaning that there is no authentication given to any user by spring security

        if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

            if (jwtTokenHelper.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
//              correct hai , authenticate krna h

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            } else {
                System.out.println("the JWT token is invalid");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("the user name is null or context is not null ");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfigs class**

```
package com.codewithdurgesh.blog.configs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;

import com.codewithdurgesh.blog.sequrity.CustomUserDetailService;
import com.codewithdurgesh.blog.sequrity.JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.codewithdurgesh.blog.sequrity.JwtAutheticationFilter;

import jakarta.servlet.Filter;

@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigs {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAutheticationFilter jwtAutheticationFilter;
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/users/getAllUser").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/api/users/getUser/{id}").hasRole("NORMAL").anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
//      .formLogin();
        
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAutheticationFilter, (Class<? extends Filter>) UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);

        httpSecurity.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());

        DefaultSecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain = httpSecurity.build();

        return defaultSecurityFilterChain;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        UserDetails normalUser = User.withUsername("ankit").password(passwordEncoder().encode("ankit")).roles("NORMAL")
                .build();

        UserDetails adminUser = User.withUsername("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin")).roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(normalUser, adminUser);

        return inMemoryDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();

    }

}
```

**AuthController Class**

```
package com.codewithdurgesh.blog.configs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;

import com.codewithdurgesh.blog.sequrity.CustomUserDetailService;
import com.codewithdurgesh.blog.sequrity.JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.codewithdurgesh.blog.sequrity.JwtAutheticationFilter;

import jakarta.servlet.Filter;

@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigs {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAutheticationFilter jwtAutheticationFilter;
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/users/getAllUser").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/api/users/getUser/{id}").hasRole("NORMAL").anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
//      .formLogin();
        
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAutheticationFilter, (Class<? extends Filter>) UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);

        httpSecurity.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());

        DefaultSecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain = httpSecurity.build();

        return defaultSecurityFilterChain;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        UserDetails normalUser = User.withUsername("ankit").password(passwordEncoder().encode("ankit")).roles("NORMAL")
                .build();

        UserDetails adminUser = User.withUsername("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin")).roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(normalUser, adminUser);

        return inMemoryDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();

    }

}
```

I added the below property in the application.properties files as this was action given in the logs

spring.main.allow-circular-references=true.

in Description it is written that

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle: --> I am not sure why how the Cycle is being created

I tried to read about the error online but I am still facing this issue.

any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A reason why you are getting this exception is in usage of `UserDetailsService` into
`JwtAutheticationFilter` and `JwtAutheticationFilter` in `SecurityConfigs` where `UserDetailsService` is creating as `Spring Bean`:

To fix it just create another config class where you are going to declare something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class UserService {

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

    UserDetails normalUser = User.withUsername("ankit").password(passwordEncoder().encode("ankit"))
        .roles("NORMAL")
        .build();

    UserDetails adminUser = User.withUsername("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
        .roles("ADMIN")
        .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(normalUser,
        adminUser);
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

}
```

And the you will be able to invoke it into `JwtAutheticationFilter` as field

```
  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;
```

and then to use it something like :

```
UserDetails userDetails = userService.userDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(userName);
```

Instead of:

```
userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
```

And like `JwtAutheticationFilter` you will inject `UserService` into `SecurityConfigs` and will use `passwordEncoder()` method.

Comment: thank you for your help I commented the userServiceDetails part. and it is working fine.

Comment: to have a working version of this one you should take my advice and it will work without commenting the code.